# In angular what does the $compile(expression)($rootScope) mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all I'm a novice JavaScript developer and I've recently started using Angular, so this might be something very obvious to a seasoned JavaScript programmer.

I have been going through tutorials online to write tests for Angular apps using Karma and Jasmine. When watching tutorials to write tests for angular directives with some HTML expressions I've often come across the method

```
$compile(htmlExpressionAsString)($scopeToWhichThisHasToBeEvaluated)
```

Some places I've seen this syntax

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/13025/files
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mu9c6-thcVU

I know from the video tutorial that it means to compile the expression and evaluate it against the scope provided in the second parenthesis.

What I don't understand is what happens behind the scenes.

How is a function that takes in an argument `$compile()`, then magically given another parenthesis with a scope argument to it? How is that syntax valid? What is the concept that I am missing here? Only asking as I couldn't find a definitive answer and I really don't know what to search for here.

Does `$compile(expression)` return a function?

Comment: Yes, the $compile service returns a linking function. For more information, see [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is valid because `$compile()` returns a function and the second `()` invokes that returned function

Simple example:

```js
function foo(a) {
  // return a function
  return function(b) {
    // return result when this function is called
    return a + b;
  }
}
let result = foo(3)(3);
console.log('Result is',result); //6
```